# How to start ActiveMQ messageListener after deploying my application using spring?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

How to start ActiveMQ messageListener after deploying my application using spring?

my xml file is given below,

-->

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="activeMQConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="messageListener" class="com.job.SampleMessageListener">
    <property name="jobResponseBean" ref="jobResponseBean"/>
    <property name="startupMessageHandlerBean" ref="startupMessageHandlerBean"/>
</bean>

<bean id="listenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="${consumer.count}"/>
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destinationName" value="general"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener"/>


enter code here
</bean>

<bean id="generalQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="general"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring should start the listenerContainer automatic when its starting/started. So if you have setup all the configuration correctly, it should happen out of the box.